# Dynamically adding rows to a UItableView with last two rows preserved for Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing problem with adding rows dynamically to a `UITableView`. I want the '**Add**' and '**Save**' button on second last and last row  of the `UITableView` respectively. How do I do that? Plus, whenever the '**Add**' button is triggered I want a row to add above the '**Add**' button. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: insert cell at what index you want.

Comment: Have you tried using different sections? (e.g. 1 for your data and 1 for your buttons)

Comment: What problem are you facing? Put some code here

Comment: Please post some code where you try to solve your problem

Comment: Which function you use to update the table, reoladData or only insert cell at index??

Comment: I hope u are using any array for showing other cell except add and save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options you have. Post some code so that we can give a better answer

1. When you set the **datasource** for the `tableView` just add `numberOfRows` plus 2 when returning the **row count**. Then in the `cellforrowatindexpath` just check for `indexpath` and add the necessary buttons.
2. You can put the add and save buttons in a separate section
3. You can ignore the **cell rows** but instead you can add buttons in the footer section of the `UItableview` section

   ```
   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   {
     //Return your view with the two buttons
   }
   ```
4. You can add the buttons in the `tableView` footer also

   ```
   yourTableView.tableFooterView = yourView; //yourView should contain the two buttons
   ```

Regarding the add button click. Just update the **datasource** array and reload the table.

Comment: Using different sections and updating the datasource array worked for me. Thanks a lot @iPrabu!

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider u are using one array name arrData for storing the record and calling `reloadData` function to reload table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ([arrData count]+2);//+2 for Add and save button
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //your code for creation of cell


   //Here check for indexpath.row

        if(indexpath.row==[[arrData count]+1])
       {
          //code for Add button
       }

          if(indexpath.row==[[arrData count]+2])
       {
           //code for save button
       }

return cell;

}
```

But my suggestion is dont include Add and save button in `UITableViewCell`  Because as your table cell get increased ADD and SAVE button go down. so each time you need scroll.

So instead include it below `UITableView`. So that each time you will get access of these buttons